# USB Device detection using Java

Tags: java, usb

Is there a way we can detect what type of device e.g andriod or iphone is connected via usb to a PC using Java programming language?

Comment: Check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831825/detect-usb-drive-in-java