# Detecting/Verifying SD Card Drive

Tags: java, windows, desktop, sd-card

Is there a way to detect all SD Card drives connected to a Desktop computer? In Windows, SD Cards are visually distinct from other devices like built-in hard drives or similar. Is there a way to tell if a drive is an SD Card drive or not?

A Java way of listing all available filesystem roots for example is using the [`listRoots()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots()) method but it cannot tell the filesystem types such as external, internal, OS drive or whatever.

Is this even possible in pure Java?

Note:
I'm **not** asking to detect the Android phone SD Card since these are the results when searching for my question.

Comment: Maybe this is, what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542018/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-drives-but-also-get-the-corresponding-drive-type-remo

Comment: @ChristophGiesche:
It's helpful but none of the answers are satisfying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22599109/3764804) answer solved it.

Example code:

```
USBDeviceDetectorManager manager = new USBDeviceDetectorManager();
List<USBStorageDevice> usbStorageDevices = manager.getRemovableDevices();

for(USBStorageDevice usbStorageDevice : usbStorageDevices)
{
    System.out.println(usbStorageDevice.getSystemDisplayName());
    System.out.println(usbStorageDevice.getDeviceName());
    System.out.println(usbStorageDevice.getRootDirectory());
}
```

I have my `SD card`, `NAS`, `C:` and `D:` drives connected. The following is printed:

```
SANDISK (E:)
SANDISK
E:\
```

As expected, only one result is returned because the `SD card` is treated as `USB` due to the `USB reader` being plugged into my laptop.

Comment: That… doesn't actually work? There isn't anything in your code which would distinguish a USB SD card from any other kind of USB storage device. And it won't pick up SD drives which aren't attached over USB (yes, they exist).

Comment: Okay but it's close enough for my purposes and most SD cards are attached via USB SD card readers these days anyway

Comment: But not all USB storage devices are SD card readers. Your code will misidentify anything else that happens to be hooked up via USB, like a flash drive or external hard disk.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I should find a better solution then