# USB programming with windows

Tags: java, c, windows, usb

I want to write a program to work with my usb port(windows).I don't know how to say this but this is how it should work.The program should run(that's should be the first thing [before virus guard ask whether this flash drive should scan]) when a flash drive or a external hard drive plugin to a usb port. I'm not talking about auto run.How can I do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Detect USB Drive in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831825/detect-usb-drive-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Library called WinUSB on windows

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303342(v=vs.85).aspx

for MAC OSX(MAC OS)
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html

for Linux Note also cross platform 
http://libusb.info/

Comment: libusb is also available for macOS and Windows, fwiw. It's kind of awkward to use in Windows, though.